# Bad performance on Windows 7 with Bad sectors

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, bad-sectors

Since a month ago everything was right with my laptop. And then Windows started crashing.
Now my windows is stuttering every 5 seconds and fails to perform smoothly any operation. There were no bad sectors. Two appeared and after I ran the chkdsk utility it says that I have 10 bad sectors on my hard drive! What's going on? I made a dual booth with Linux so that I can use my computer at least, and I have no problems with Linux. Can it be system related.
I got a lot of crashes and from what I see they are all
KERNEL_INPAGE_FAULT_DATA which means there is corruption in the pagefile.sys, but when I deleted it nothing changed. I use my Linux OS with no problem.

The most likely reason is that ntoskernel.exe is corrupted -----> the paging system in the kernel causes bad data to be written hence when I re-open a window the corrupted data to the RAM.

Should I wipe my disk to zero-fill the bad sectors? is there another approach? Will wiping the windows partition also delete the Linux partition? Well I don't have any important stuff on my Linux, and I can backup my data on the Windows side.

Does HDD Regenerator work? I'm tempted to test it, but I can't seem to rely on any user feedback.

Comment: Bad sectors indicate that your hard drive will die soon. Boot a live distro, mount partitions as read-only and make backups ASAP.

Answer (score 3):

Like [gronostaj](https://superuser.com/users/194694/gronostaj) has pointed out in [a comment on the question](https://superuser.com/questions/744026/bad-performance-on-windows-7-with-bad-sectors#comment958087_744026), bad sectors (especially when you see more and more of them quickly) are a very good sign that your computer's hard drive is at the end of its life and is likely to fail in the very near future. Some of your data has likely already been irretrievably lost; hopefully the damage so far is in mostly unused areas of the disk.

This is not something that can be fixed using software. Software *may* be able to detect which sectors are bad *now* and ensure that those are not used moving forward, but it's not going to do anything to stop the degredation that is happening on the physical level.

What you need to do is to **right now backup everything on that hard drive that you care about,** then **replace the hard drive** with a new one, preferably before your current one fails completely.

Some hard drives seem to be able to survive rapidly developing bad sectors and come back to life, but ask yourself: will you ever again trust this hard drive with anything even remotely important? My guess is probably not. So just accept the fact that it's showing clear signs of possible imminent failure, and act accordingly.

Comment: The drive is 320 GB. I'll use it at most 2 more months. After that I'll get a new setup w/ 2x4 TB HDD and 2x256 GB SSD. Will the current drive survive until then? It devloped 8 bad sectors for 3 days.
Or should I get a new one? Perferably 500GB

Comment: @Arctic **It's impossible to say how long the drive will last.** Maybe it'll effectively die ten minutes from now because it develops a bad sector in a critical metadata area, or maybe it'll survive for another year or more. Basically one of two things can happen. Either the bad sectors are just bad luck, and you won't see many more (such things happen); or, it's really physical damage and it'll simply keep getting worse, potentially in an exponential fashion. The key question is, how much do you care about the data on that drive?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Don't care too much about the data neither the drive. As I said temporary laptop to feed my needs.

Comment: @Arctic If you can live with potentially losing everything on that drive right now, just keep using it until you can replace it with and transfer the data to your new setup. Personally, I care much more about my data than that, but everyone is different and it certainly depends on what you're using the laptop for. I suppose that's another way of phrasing the "accept the fact that it's showing clear signs of possible imminent failure, and act accordingly" at the end of the answer.

Comment: @Arctic If you feel this answer properly answers your question, please indicate so by upvoting and/or accepting. [That is the customary way of saying thanks on Stack Exchange.](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer)