# Does my hard drive has a bad sector?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bad-sectors

I ran Windows drive error check and got this message:

```
Windows replaced bad clusters in file ######
```

Does this mean that my hard drive now has a bad sector and it needs to be replaced? Or is this just a software issue?

Note: the test was on my boot drive.

Comment: Yes. Time to urgently back up your drive and replace it.

Comment: A healthy HDD does not have corrupt files.  This failure is hardware not software (the file system)

Comment: even if it was one bad sector do i need to replace it , and do this mean that the rest of the hard drive will be corrupted ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bad performance on Windows 7 with Bad sectors](http://superuser.com/questions/744026/bad-performance-on-windows-7-with-bad-sectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if it was one bad sector do I need to replace it, and do this mean that the rest of the hard drive will be corrupted?

[Michael Kjörling](https://superuser.com/users/53590/michael-kj%c3%b6rling)'s [answer on this SU question](https://superuser.com/a/744032/23133) covers this very well, so I'll just snag his text as it directly applies:

---

Bad sectors (especially when you see more and more of them quickly) are a very good sign that your computer's hard drive is at the end of its life and is likely to fail in the very near future. Some of your data has likely already been irretrievably lost; hopefully the damage so far is in mostly unused areas of the disk.

This is not something that can be fixed using software. Software *may* be able to detect which sectors are bad *now* and ensure that those are not used moving forward, but it's not going to do anything to stop the degradation that is happening on the physical level.

What you need to do is to **right now backup everything on that hard drive that you care about,** then **replace the hard drive** with a new one, preferably before your current one fails completely.

Some hard drives seem to be able to survive rapidly developing bad sectors and come back to life, but ask yourself: will you ever again trust this hard drive with anything even remotely important? My guess is probably not. So just accept the fact that it's showing clear signs of possible imminent failure, and act accordingly.

---

If you found this answer useful, please go to the cited answer and up-vote Michael. :)

Comment: Actually, it's not unusual for drives to come from the factory with defective sectors.

Comment: However, newer drives hide this from the user and provide internal replacement for bad sectors from a pool.  Thus if you are seeing this at a USER level, it means that internal drive pool to recover this type of problem have been exhausted.  Thus it is time to get a new disk.